# Add zero-padding to count in Chef (ruby) loop

Tags: ruby, loops, templates, chef-infra

I have a loop in a chef recipe that is part of a template and I would like to zero-pad it to 2 digits. I have used `puts "%02d" % i` as well as `sprintf '%02d', i` , neither of which are working and simply output no text in the template. I have checked that the value of `i` is OK.

Cut-down version of the code:

```
<% node["cpu"]["total"].times do |i|
i = i + 1 %>

name fluentd-instance<% sprintf '%02d', i %>

....

<% end -%>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= sprintf '%02d', i %>
```

You need the equals sign, right?

Comment: Great. Thank you. I thought that a sprintf would 'natively' print the text and thus `<%` should be used instead of `<%=`.

Comment: `sprintf` *returns* the value. It looks like you're in a template (ERB?), and to have the value included in the template, you have to use `<%= %>`. `puts` will simply print the value to STDOUT, which isn't what you want.